# 3-D numpy matrix multiplication in numpy to get 1 D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've 2 3-D matrix of this form:

`a = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(3, 4, 3))`

`b = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(3,3, 4))`

I want to multiply these 2 matrices, in such a way that I get a matrix of this form:

`a_b = np.random.normal(0,1,size = (3,1))`

I can change the matrix shape of `b` in anyway to get `a_b` shape. E.g. I can make `b 2X2 matrix` or change the shape of the matrix in any other way.

Can someone please guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think pure multiplication can get you to that shape without some kind of aggregation like summation...

Comment: **(a)** When you say "I want to multiply" do you really mean "multiply" as in matrix multiplication, or do you mean "somehow combine" ? **(b)** Normal matrix multiplication can never get you what you have asked for because the first matrix has values ranging from 1 to 100 and the second has values ranging from 0 to 1, and you are asking for the result to have values from 0 to 1. **(c)** Do you want the numbers in a_b to have normal distribution? (That's what your current phrasing of the question seems to imply)

Comment: @fountainhead: Thanks for your interest to my question! a) I want to multiply the 2 matrices. b) The matrix `a_b` can have any values. I just used `np.random.normal` to show the dimension and how the final matrix will look like. It's an example. c) No. I don't want it to be normally distributed. It will be multiplication of 2 matrices. So, it can have any values. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by @gmds, no matter what shape your `b` is, given that `a` is of shape `(3,4,3)`, I don't think you can ever get a shape `(3,1)` by normal matrix multiplication.

Comment: @fountainhead: Thanks for reply. I'll not spend time on this problem anymore then.